# Is that series convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a series given below and I have to check if it converges or diverges. $$\sum_{2}^\infty    \frac{1}{\ln(n)^{\ln(n)}}$$
I decided for a comprasion test. Firstly, I converted  denominator so that; $\ln(n)^{\ln(n)}=n^{\ln(\ln(n))} $ (quick trick using properties of "e" number.)
Next step - comparison with using inequalities:$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\geqslant \frac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln(n))}} \Rightarrow  n^2 \leqslant n^{ln(ln(n))} $$
But it holds only for $n\geqslant e^{e^2}$.
Because I know that $\sum_{1}^\infty    \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges I did the following : $$\sum_{2}^\infty    \frac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln(n))}} =\sum_ {2}^{\lfloor e^{e^2}\rfloor}    \frac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln(n))}}(=A)+\sum_{\lceil e^{e^2}\rceil}^\infty   \frac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln(n))}}(=B)$$ I called first part as A, and second part as B. I assumed that $-\infty \lt A\lt \infty \Rightarrow $ convergence. That is because we sum up to the finite number = $\lfloor e^{e^2}\rfloor$. Since our inequality holds for $n\geqslant e^{e^2}$ I did a comprasion test only for B.
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\geqslant \frac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln(n))}} \Rightarrow \sum_{\lceil e^{e^2}\rceil}^\infty    \frac{1}{n^2} \geqslant \sum_{\lceil e^{e^2}\rceil}^\infty    \frac{1}{n^{\ln(\ln(n))}}=B $$ $\sum_{\lceil e^{e^2}\rceil}^\infty    \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges and it is greater than series "B" implies that B converges as WELL.

Is my thinking correct? Have I done any mistakes ?

Comment: this sounds good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is fine but we can simplify it indeed what really matters is that eventually as $n>n_0$ for some $n_0$ (we don’t need to find it explicitly)

$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\geqslant \frac{1}{n^{ln(ln(n))}} $$

and therefore the convergence is guaranteed since the the summation of the first $n_0$ values is finite.

Comment: @paweta Yes of course full explanation are fine and is good you go in deep reasoning for practice. My suggestion could be useful in order to use a more concise argument and save time in an exam. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: that's completely right, but knowing the "very clear" way to do it , and the basics, is important for better understanding, and faster learning new stuff.

Comment: I fully agree with you!

Answer (score 0):

You have that
$$\frac{n^2}{\ln(n)^{\ln(n)}} = \exp\left[ \ln(n) \left( 2 - \ln(\ln(n)) \right)\right] \rightarrow 0$$

so $$\frac{1}{\ln(n)^{\ln(n)}} = o \left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

and by comparison, the series converges.

Comment: So what you have done is, comprasion RATIO TEST and i guess u divided 1/lnn^lnn by 1/n^2, knowing that 1/n^2 as a sum converges,  and u took a limit of this fraction. But finally it gave u 0=/=1, and it doesn't say anything, since those series are not the same size

Comment: @paweta Why $0 \neq 1$ ? I didn't use ratio test, just comparison test. I proved that $1/(ln(n)^{ln(n)}$ is a $o(1/n^2)$ (by computing directly the limit of the quotient), and because the series $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, it is enough to say that the original one also converges.

Comment: limit comprasion test says that:Suppose that we have two series An and Bn, C=lim An/Bn, If C is positive and finite then either both series converge or both series diverge.

Comment: positive means GREATER than 0, but when we have C=0as s result of our limit, we cant conclude anything

Comment: meaning C, strictly greater than 0

Comment: This is known as “limit comparison test”.

Comment: @paweta I am not using limit comparison test, but just the classical comparison test for positive series. If $A_n/B_n$ tends to $0$, with $A_n$ and $B_n$ positive, and $\sum B_n$ converges, then $\sum A_n$ converges.

Comment: Well, you said TENDS to 0, so there is no way you are not using limit.

Comment: you compare two series, so if the quotient is 0,  means that, one of the(numerator or denominator) is way bigger than the other.

Comment: @paweta I don't care about how the result is called, if it is called "limit comparison  test" or "direct comparison test". The result of my previous comment is true and elementary, and should appear in every textbook. If you are not convinced, try to prove it.

Comment: @paweta Ok. Then see what is written in the theorem 2.5 (on page 2), 2. on the following document : https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~ratazzi/chapitre-1-bozec.pdf This is **exactly** what I use.

Comment: @paweta It is not because a theorem of yours does not say something that this thing is false. I am trying to help you, so maybe you should not reject systematically what I say because "it is not stated in my theorem".

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Indeed it is not important as a name but usually this method in known as [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: @user Yes, but I don't know why the OP thinks it cannot be applied here... Apparently, his comparison test does not mention the case where the limit is $0$.